# Having trouble with Wordpress standard gallery images

Tags: css, wordpress, image, alignment, gallery

My wordpress gallery is aligning itself vertically rather than default grid format. To fix the CSS, I am using:

```
#gallery-1 #gallery-item {display:inline; clear:both; width:auto; height:auto;}
```

Examples can be seen on the following links:

http://stayingurgaon.com/dine-drinks-gurgaon/american-restaurants-gurgaon/tgi-fridays-gurgaon-review-mg-road.html

http://stayingurgaon.com/dine-drinks-gurgaon/holy-smoke-cyber-hub-gurgaon.html (Under tab restaurant photos)

But it doesn't seem to work at all. Request help. Thank you.

Comment: You are styling with id `#gallery-item` while in HTML you have used class. Use `#gallery-1 .gallery-item {display:inline;clear:both;width:auto;height:auto;}`

Comment: Thanks Usman .. But this code didn't work.

Comment: `#gallery-1 .gallery-item {display:inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 33.33%;}` should work. You can change width according to your needs

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks very much Usman ... Much appreciated.